# What happen with further clicks

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I have an observable that will throw an error, when the counter will be reach 5:

```
let counter = 0;

const source2 = Rx.Observable.of(true)
    .map(() => [1,2,3,4,5]);

source2
    .subscribe((x) => console.log(x),
               (err) => console.log(err),
               () => console.log("complete 2!!"));


const source1 = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click')
    .do(() => console.log("Document clicked!"))
    .do(() => counter++)
    .map(() => {

      if(counter > 5) {
        counter = 0;
        throw new Error("Counter is too big!");
      }

      return true;

    })
    .catch((oError, oSource$) => source2)


source1
    .subscribe((x) => console.log(x),
               (err) => console.log(err),
               () => console.log("complete!!"));
```

When the error got threw, then it will switch to `source2` as you can see on the code above.

When I make further clicks on the document, nothing will happen why? What happen with further clicks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the basic rxjs-paradigms: Whenever an error is thrown in a stream (no matter if it is a direct `throw new Error(..)` or `Observable.throw(...)`) the subscribed stream is automatically *finalized* and subscribers are unsubscribed.

So the behavior is expected.

To *fix* this in your personal case: Don't throw an error if you don't want your stream to stop and unless you want to resubscribe manually.

Addition: The [`catch`-operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-catch) just allows for reacting to an error within the stream, independently from any subscriber - the stream itself will still be finalized though - the name `catch` kind of gives a false impression here. - You can *"retry"* the observable by returning the original source in the `catch`-operator, which will effectively create a new stream based on that source, the old stream, however, will still be finalized.

Comment: As a general __personal__ side-note: __Don't__ throw exceptions for semantic issues like in your case where some data is reaching some semantic limit. (I don't know your code, but it looks to me that way) - Errors/Exceptions are meant to be thrown for __technical__ issues, like e.g. when a required parameter is missing or if the received data has not the expected structure. -- Maybe you can describe your desired scenario - I'm sure this can be handled by rxjs in an elegant manner without throwing errors.

Comment: What I do not understand is, when I return in the catch method the source like: `.catch((oError, oSource$) => oSource$)` then the subscribers will be not unsubscribed, why?

Comment: the `catch`-operator is just a convenience-operator that allows for reacting to an error within the stream, independently from any subscriber -  the stream will still be finalized

Comment: But I do not understand, why when I return `oSource$` it will subscribe as usual even the stream finalized. It's not going into my brain.

Comment: What you return in the `catch`-operator is the observable the subscriber will _switch_ to - `oSource$` is the original source, if you return it in the `catch` operator the subscriber will make a new subscription based on it - but the old one will still be finalized: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-catch

Comment: So when I return `source2` instead of  `oSource$` then `source1` will be unsubscribed and further clicks is not going stream anymore, right?

Comment: Absolutely correct - But also: source1 will always be unsubscribed because of the error, but you can "reactivate" the subscription by doing `(...) => oSource$`) - so rxjs will automatically create a new subscription on that source (technically it is a __new__ stream though - just on the same source

Comment: @osln thousand thanks for helping me to understand catch.

Comment: It is a complex topic - that was also one of the most difficult things for me to understand in the beginning, that the catch-operator works a little different from what one is used to in plain js